# Setting a delayed shutdown time on a remote LInux via SSH then exiting

Tags: ssh, exit, shutdown, flush

I have looked at all the answers here on SOF, and not seen what would work.

### My goal:

Have a EC2 QA server halt itself 55 minutes after last usage

### My strategy:

Everytime the remote machine is used, it is first checked to see if it is running. If it is, then do the following:

1. ssh into machine
2. run 'sudo shutdown -c' #clears last pending shutdown
3. run 'sudo shutdown -h +55' #restarts timer for 55 minute shutdown
4. exit

Go about my script's business

### What Works:

All commands work locally 1 and 2. Numbers 3 and 4 are partial as explained below.

### What Doesn't Work:

The line invoking the new shutdown halt, it waits for the ssh connection to shutdown, which never does for the versions of the command without '&' at the end.

### What I've tried:

echo "nohup sudo shutdown -h +55; exit" | ssh -i $HOME/.ec2/cert_name root_user_name@i.p.ad.dress

echo "nohup sudo shutdown -h +55& exit" | ssh -i $HOME/.ec2/cert_name root_user_name@i.p.ad.dress

echo "sudo shutdown -h +55& exit" | ssh -i $HOME/.ec2/cert_name root_user_name@i.p.ad.dress

ssh -i $HOME/.ec2/cert_name root_user_name@i.p.ad.dress nohup sudo shutdown -h +55

ssh -i $HOME/.ec2/cert_name root_user_name@i.p.ad.dress nohup sudo shutdown -h +55; exit

### What Sort Of Works:

ssh -i $HOME/.ec2/cert_name root_user_name@i.p.ad.dress nohup sudo shutdown -h +55&

ssh -i $HOME/.ec2/cert_name root_user_name@i.p.ad.dress sudo shutdown -h +55&

### What is 'Sort Of':

The partially successful commands set up the shutdown, and exit ssh just fine. But they fills the LOCAL screen buffer with the last command results on the REMOTE screen. And that comes out with the results of the next command in the script.

I suppose that I could just issue 'echo "flushing buffer"' twice in a row and clear it.

Anything more complete and cleaner out there?

TIA

Comment: While I would still like to know the answer to this. I have found a problem in the overall design. During the last 5 minutes of a shutdown command, no logins are allowed. So I always would have this 5 minute window that server could be stuck in that the build or script would have to wait for.

Comment: Try looking on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) and perhaps [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) as well.

Comment: @dave4420 thanks for the great idea! I actually have a solution to this that I will post. It completely removes the window problem.

Comment: Thanks Dave, don't know if SOF got the last thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

OK, 4 days later, I have something that works pretty good. I did NOT see anything like this on google or stack overflow searches.

Essentially, a cheap server is used as a keep alive (for 120 minutes) or restart (if already timed out) controller for a more expensive server. There are hints on how to do it for more complex setups than (1 cheap server)->(1 expensive server). Otherwise known as a 'exercise for the reader' :-)

https://github.com/kwince/costlyServerShutDown

The trigger to keep alive or restart is doing a 'wget' to file on the apache server root of the cheap server. Again, quick and dirty, but very effective.

Comment: I have been using this now for 3 months. There have been no problems, except my error checking was not complete enough to tell what was going on during the recent AWS issues in Virginia. But otherwise, it's now saved me about 180 dollars.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to shutdown after `<time>` seconds even if you exit SSH-connection:

```
( sleep <time>; sudo shutdown now ) &
```

provided your *sudoers* file allows shutdown without password.